# Big gap centering 2 column form with foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have a simple 2-column form that I want centered on the page.  Not sure why there's a 3 inch gap in between the columns

```
<form id="frm" action="profile" method="post" class="custom">
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-4 small-centered columns">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="small-1 columns"><span id="makemeboldlbl" class="inline radius secondary label right">Email:</span></div>
        <div class="small-3 columns"><input type="email" id="profile_email" value="test@test.com" /></div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="small-1 columns"><span id="makemeboldlbl" class="inline radius secondary label right">Username:</span></div>
        <div class="small-3 columns"><input type="text" id="profile_username" value="TestIt" /></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think the OP get a better answer before i wrote..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep.Its Nothing but in foundation row's are basically  divided into 12 columns okay but in here you are having only two columns, In foundation by default the last column of a row floated into right side.see here check it from your firebug

```
     [class*="column"] + [class*="column"]:last-child {
       float: right;
   }
```

in this case you can use your override class for example

```
     .left{
           float:left !important;
       }
```

and add it your html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-1 columns"><span id="makemeboldlbl" class="inline radius secondary label right">Email:</span></div>
    <div class="small-3 columns left"><input type="email" id="profile_email" value="test@test.com" /></div>
 </div>
```

simple.. :)